# How to apply ngStyle to :host element in component?

Tags: angular, shadow-dom, angular2-template

I have something like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'column',
    template: '<ng-content></ng-content>'
})
export class ColumnComponent {

    @Input() columnWidth: string = '0';        

    constructor() {}
}
```

and I wanna apply property **columnWidth** to **[ngStyle]** on

```
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

parent element, to do something like this:

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'width': columnWidth+'px'}" > ....
```

I know how to apply style to host element:

```
:host {  /*styles*/  }
```

but I don't know to pass parameters to it.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There is no way to do this.

What you can do is

```ts
@HostBinding('style.width')
width:string = '10px';
```

or

```ts
@HostBinding('style.width.px')
width:number = '10';
```

The main limitation is that the `width` part is fixed and can't be used from a variable.

Another way with full flexibility is

```ts
constructor(private elRef:ElementRef, private renderer:Renderer) {}

setStyles() {
  this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.elRef.nativeElement, 'width', '10px');
}
```

Comment: I have error: Can't bind to 'columnWidth' since it isn't a known native property ("        <ecrm-topbar-search></ecrm-topbar-search>
                </column>
                <column [ERROR ->][columnWidth]="150" >

Comment: If you want to bind the input value to the style `@HostBinding('style.width.px')@Input() columnWidth: string = '0';` should work. What have you tried?

Comment: 10 stars for this answer! :)

Comment: I hate that I have to go all the way to the renderer but this is the only way to apply styles to the Host that I can find

Comment: [Günter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/217408/g%c3%bcnter-z%c3%b6chbauer), can you clarify the statement "The main limitation is that the width part is fixed and can't be used from a variable."  -> My coworker critisized my use of `Render2` and gave example of setting width with variable with `HostBinding`.  [See stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hostbinding-width?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)

Comment: I didn't say you can't set `with`, what I said is that the `.width` part can not come from a variable, like for example `foo ? style.width.px : style.height.px`.

Comment: Got it..  Thanks for clarification :)

Answer (score 7):

I actually used @GunterZochbauer 's solution but he mentioned that you cannot use a variable. Maybe at that time that was right but with the latest angular, you totally could.

```ts
@HostBinding('style.width.px')
get width(): number {
  return state.width;
}
```

I'm using state management to set the width and then apply it directly to the host element. It works great!